# Belgian yeast used to brew a stout

Tags: fermentation

I accidentally pitched wyeast 1762 instead if yeast 1056 to brew a stout. Is my beer ruined? Before I pitch the right into the mix and really make a mess of things can anyone with more knowledge guide me please?

Comment: You pitched both full yeast packs into your wort?

Comment: No I only pitched the 1762

Comment: Might turn out closer to a Tropical stout, but probably not ruined, just experimental

Answer (score 3):

"Ruined"? No. But 1762 still definitely create a different ester profile than 1056.

If you really want a traditional american stout profile, then… 1762 is reported to ferment "clean" at the low end of its temperature range, near 65. Pitch the 1056 as well, that will help limit how much 1762 ferments. If you can control the fermentation temperature, then ferment in the low 60's especially for the first few days, then raise the temp a bit to help fermentation finish off.

Or, just let it go as is and see if you like your Belgian-style stout. :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch let's see how the Belgian style stout turns out.